# Why a matrix with normalized vectors whose elements are iid Gaussian satisfy restricted isometry property.

Tags: linear-algebra, probability-theory, probability-distributions

On page 23, section 4.1, [the well-known paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0506081.pdf) by Candes et al. lays out the way of constructing a matrix $A$ satisfying the restricted isometry property as follows:

Sampling from Gaussian distribution independently for each entry of a column to create that column and then normalizing the column to be the column of $A$.

**Question**: Why does such a procedure guarantee that the isometry property is preserved for matrix $A$? Also, what would be the restricted isometry constant $\delta_s$?

**Definition**:  Let $\mathbf{A}$ be an $m\times p$ matrix and let $1 \leq s \leq p$ be an integer. Suppose that there exists a constant $\delta _{s}\in (0,1)$ such that  every $s$-sparse vector $\mathbf{v}$ satisfies

\begin{align}
    (1-\delta _{s})\|\mathbf{v}\|_2^2 \leq \|\mathbf{A}\mathbf{v}\|_2^2 \leq (1+\delta _{s})\|\mathbf{v}\|_2^2
\end{align}

Then, the matrix $\mathbf{A}$ is said to satisfy the $s$-restricted isometry property with restricted isometry constant $\delta_s$.

Comment: I think this is essentially Theorem 5.65 from Roman Vershynin's [excellent chapter](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1011.3027.pdf).

Comment: @VHarisop: Thank you. That answers my question. You can write it as an answer formally and explain it a little bit more(in a couple of lines).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that your matrix $A$ satisfies
$$
A \overset{(d)}{=} \frac{1}{\sqrt{m}} \tilde{A},
$$
where $\tilde{A}$ is a matrix with zero-mean independent columns $A_{:, i}$ satisfying $\| A_{:, i} \|_2 = \sqrt{m}$. By [Theorem 5.65 in this paper [1]](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1011.3027.pdf), such matrices are restricted isometries and satisfy with high probability:
$$
(1 - \delta_{s}) \| x\|_2^2 \leq \| Ax \|_2^2 \leq (1 + \delta_{s}) \|x \|_2^2, \;  \quad \text{simultaneously over all $s$-sparse $x$}.
$$
Here, we can drive $\delta_{s}$ arbitrarily close to $0$ by choosing $
m \geq \frac{C}{\delta_s^2} s \log(e p / s),
$
where $C$ is a constant.

[1]: Roman Vershynin, *Introduction to the non-asymptotic analysis of random matrices* (2011 version).